# DevExpress Inline Edit - Cascaded ComboBox - Load based on another column value change

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I am working on inline edit. I am able to load a combo box "InternalFaciltyName" in the gird based on "FacilityID"column value using CellEditorInitialize, but I need to reload the combo box when the "FacilityID" column value is changed during edit.

I have used CustomCallBack on "FacilityID" change to get the changed value but I am not able to access the combo box control using FindEditFormTemplateControl.
It returns null. Below is my code.

```
                            ConfirmDelete="True" KeyFieldName="ID"  
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
                            CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Office2003 Blue/{0}/styles.css"  
                            CssPostfix="Office2003_Blue"  
                           OnCustomCallback="ASPxGridView_CustomCallback"  
                           OnRowDeleting="ASPxGridView_RowDeleting"  
                           OnRowUpdating="ASPxGridView_RowUpdating"  
                           OnRowValidating="ASPxGridView_RowValidating"  
                          OnCellEditorInitialize="ASPxGridView_CellEditorInitialize" >  

                            <SettingsText ConfirmDelete="Are you sure you want to Delete?" />  
                            <SettingsEditing Mode="Inline" />  

                            <Columns>  
                                <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Visible="false" Caption="ID" FieldName="ID"   ShowInCustomizationForm="True">  
                                </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>  
                                <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Facility Id" FieldName="FacilityID" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" Width="20%">  
                                 <PropertiesTextEdit>  
                                 <ClientSideEvents TextChanged="function(s, e) {ASPxGridView.PerformCallback(ASPxGridView.GetEditValue(&quot;FacilityID&quot;)+&quot;|&quot;+&quot;facilityChange&quot;);  
                               }"/></PropertiesTextEdit>  
                                </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>  

                                <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Facility Name" FieldName="FacilityName" ShowInCustomizationForm="True">  
                                </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>  

                                <dxwgv:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn Caption="Internal Facility Name" FieldName="InternalFacilityName"                                ShowInCustomizationForm="True">  
                                </dxwgv:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>  

                               <dxwgv:GridViewCommandColumn ButtonType="Image" Width="10%">  
                                    <EditButton Text="Edit" Visible="True">  
                                        <Image Url="~/Images/Edit.gif" />  
                                        <Image Url="~/Images/Edit.gif"></Image>  
                                    </EditButton>  
                                    <DeleteButton Text="Delete" Visible="True">  
                                        <Image Url="~/Images/Delete.gif" />  
                                        <Image Url="~/Images/Delete.gif"></Image>  
                                         </DeleteButton>  
                                         <CancelButton Text="Cancel">  
                                <Image Url="~/Images/Cancel.gif" />  
                                <Image Url="~/Images/Cancel.gif"></Image>  
                            </CancelButton>  
                            <UpdateButton Text="Update">  
                                <Image Url="~/Images/Update.gif" />  
                                      <Image Url="~/Images/Update.gif"></Image>  
                            </UpdateButton>  

                                </dxwgv:GridViewCommandColumn>  
                           </column>  
                        </dxwgv:ASPxGridView>  


protected void ASPxGridView_CellEditorInitialize(object sender, ASPxGridViewEditorEventArgs e)  
    {  
        if ((ASPxGridView.IsEditing) && (e.Column.FieldName == "InternalFacilityName"))  
        {  
                ASPxComboBox combo = e.Editor as ASPxComboBox;  
                var facilityID = ASPxGridView.GetRowValuesByKeyValue(e.KeyValue, "FacilityID");  

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
                dt = GetFacilityList(facilityID.ToString());  
                combo.DataSource = dt;  
                combo.TextField = "FacName";  
                combo.ValueField = "FacName";  
                combo.DataBind();  
            }  
    }  
 protected void ASPxGridView_CustomCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)  
    {  
        SetCookies(sender, e);  
        if (e.Parameters.ToString().Contains("|"))  
        {  
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
            string[] MyParameters = e.Parameters.ToString().Split('|');  
            string ParameterName = MyParameters[1].Trim();  
            if (ParameterName == "facilityChange")  
            {  
                ASPxGridView grid = (ASPxGridView)sender;  
                dt = GetFacilityList(MyParameters[0].Trim());  

                ASPxComboBox combo = ASPxGridView.FindEditFormTemplateControl("InternalFacilityName") as ASPxComboBox;  
                combo.DataSource = dt;  
                combo.TextField = "FacName";  
                combo.ValueField = "FacName";  
                combo.DataBind();  
            }  
        } 
}` 


Please advice on this. Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current implementation has two cons:

- The ASPxGridView CustomCallback is too exceeded. It reloads the entire grid, while it is necessary to reload a single ASPxComboBox,
- The "InternalFacilityName" column does not define a template. So, the use of the ASPxGridView.ASPxGridView.FindEditFormTemplateControl always returns null.

Subscribe, perform and handle "InternalFacilityName" ASPxComboBox callback instead. Check out the [Cascading Combo Boxes](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/CascadingComboBoxes.aspx) demo.